# Registering for jQuery(window).load(...) event, after the event has fired?

Tags: jquery

I am new to the group and just had a simple question about the jQuery(window).load(function() {});.

I have an external JS file that gets inserted dynamically on the page "after" the window load event occurs. Inside this JS file I have a statement as follows:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    alert("Something");
});
```

The question I have is, would the alert() statement above get executed because by the time my above function gets registered to the window load event, the event has already fired. I would expect the alert above to fire immediately since the event it is supposed to wait on, is already complete.

I appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably should use `jQuery(document).load( ... )` instead.

Comment: Also: what does happen currently?

Comment: Currently it does not fire. I think it would have made more sense to fire the function immediately. Since, the coder, intended his function to be executed after the window onload event has occurred and jQuery should be intelligent enough to understand that since the event has occurred, we should call the function right away.

Comment: jQuery offers a mechanism for this: `$(document).ready(function() { })`, why does this code not use that, does it need images to be loaded?

Comment: This code embeds some flash on the page and taking some latency issues in consideration, I don't want the load event to be blocked on the flash to complete loading. Thus I want to embed this flash after the window load event occurs. Also, the entire embed logic is inside an external JS file which is also fetched after the load event, which is why I had this question.

Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it would not fire, however, you can invoke the event after inserting like this:

```
$(window).load(); //or.. $(window).trigger('load');
```

This will trigger that code to run.

Using `document.ready` will fire immediately when included after the document is already ready, but `$(window).load(function() {... })` is explicitly binding to the window's load event, which has already fired.

Comment: Thanks! I expected the behavior to be a little more intelligent but I get your point here. I will try to register my function to the load event before it actually fires. (More in the comment above).

Answer (score 1):

This problem bit me too. I guess it can be risky to add 'load' callback to late after the page loads — since it won't get called *at all* if the 'load' event has already been fired!

I completely agree —  I too expected my callback to get called immediately since the event it was supposed to wait on was already complete. It seems like that would be more consistent with the way the document 'ready' event immediately fires its callbacks if the document is already ready...

Here is my workaround, written in CoffeeScript:

```
$(window).on 'load', ->
  window._loaded = true

window.on_window_load_safe = (callback) ->
  if window._loaded
    # Since the load even already happened, if we tried to add a new callback now, it would not even
    # get called. So just call the callback immediately now.
    callback.call()
  else
    $(window).on 'load', ->
      callback.call()
```

You can test it with something like this:

```
  setTimeout(->
    on_window_load_safe ->
      console.debug 'on_window_load_safe called me'
  , 2000)
```